# commit-interval="3" always replaces data by 3 times on writing

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using SpringBatch on Sample code.

SpringBatch supports chunk oriented programming, so I tried to use commit-interval attribute.

My job configuration is like this

```
<batch:job id="csv2xmlJob">
    <batch:step id="csv2xmlStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="csvFileItemReader" processor="filterProcessor"
                writer="xmlFileItemWriter" commit-interval="5"></batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<!-- csv file reader -->
<bean id="csvFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="file:report.csv"></property>
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="firstName, lastName"></property>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="person"></property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- xml file writer -->
<bean id="xmlFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:person.xml"></property>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="personUnmarshaller2"></property>
    <property name="rootTagName" value="info3"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="personUnmarshaller2" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.mycode.batch.Person</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and here is csv format

```
CUBA,DOE
JACKSON,DOE
JILL,DOE
JOHN,DOE
BOO,DOE
```

in above code, I set 5 for commit-interval and then 
every time I run this code, last item is written by 5 times to xml file.

output xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<info3>
    <person>
        <firstname>BOO</firstname>
        <lastname>DOE</lastname>
    </person>
    <person>
        <firstname>BOO</firstname>
        <lastname>DOE</lastname>
    </person>
    <person>
        <firstname>BOO</firstname>
        <lastname>DOE</lastname>
    </person>
    <person>
        <firstname>BOO</firstname>
        <lastname>DOE</lastname>
    </person>
    <person>
        <firstname>BOO</firstname>
        <lastname>DOE</lastname>
    </person>
</info3>
```

I really don't know why the writer duplicates item.

[UPDATED]
when I set commit-interval to 1, it works without problem. 
this is my processor code. it just simply replace string to uppercase.

```
public class FilterProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Person, Person> {

    @Override
    public Person process(Person person) throws Exception {
        String firstName = person.getFirstName().toUpperCase();
        String lastName = person.getLastName().toUpperCase();

        Person processedPerson = new Person(firstName, lastName);

        System.out.println(processedPerson.toString());

        return processedPerson;
    }

}
```

Comment: Before I start make some assumptions, I want to ask if you tried it with the commit-interval="1" and get correct results.

Comment: Show us your processor code...maybe there is a problem

Comment: @SelimOk thanks for reply. I got correct results when I set commit-interval=1.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci I updated processor code. it is very simple so I can't find any problem

Comment: And if the chunking enabled (I mean commit-interval greater than 1) writes the System.out.println() correct output on the console?

Comment: It's really weird and may be an implementation problem of ItemWriter. Do you have the chance to use an alternative ItemWriter and see the results?

Comment: If you throw this into a Gist I can grab, I can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and could be resolved by changing the BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper for custom fieldSetMapper in this way is not necessary to put the commit-interval by 1